# Permission required to SET XACT_ABORT

Tags: sql-server-2008, vba, set

I'm running a VBA proc from Excel against SQL 2008 R2. The SQL does several inserts in 3 table (invoice batch, header and lines) all wrapped in a transaction (so, couldn't be done in a stored procedure - I don't think).

I recently had an issue where a transaction was left open because of a lost connection and it caused quite a few issues.

So, I added SET XACT_ABORT ON after I open the connection. Up until now the VBA has been running with SQL creds and way too high permissions. We will be switching to Windows authentication and minimal required permissions.

I searched BOL, but couldn't find an answer about what permissions are required to run SET XACT_ABORT ON. I clearly don't want to give them sysadmin, if this is the answer. If it is, any other suggestions to ensure a lost connection will not leave an open tran?

TIA

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any documentation on this, but trying it out implies **no special permissions required**.

**More info**

I created a user which only had `PUBLIC` access to the database, then logged in as this user and ran the below SQL.

All ran successfully, implying that no special permissions are required to run the `SET XACT_ABORT ...` statement.

```
set xact_abort on
select 'hello'
set xact_abort off
```